# Python 3: How to properly add new Futures to a list while already waiting upon it?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and a list. And with the following code I add futures to the ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
for id in id_list:
    future = self._thread_pool.submit(self.myfunc, id)
    self._futures.append(future)
```

And then I wait upon the list:

```
concurrent.futures.wait(self._futures)
```

However, `self.myfunc` does some network I/O and thus there will be some network exceptions. When errors occur, `self.myfunc` submits a new `self.myfunc` with the same `id` to the same thread pool and add a new future to the same list, just as the above:

```
try:
    do_stuff(id)
except:
    future = self._thread_pool.submit(self.myfunc, id)
    self._futures.append(future)
    return None
```

Here comes the problem: I got an error on the line of `concurrent.futures.wait(self._futures)`:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 277, in wait
    f._waiters.remove(waiter)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

How should I properly add new Futures to a list while already waiting upon it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `wait()`, it certainly doesn't expect that anything outside `concurrent.futures` will ever mutate the list passed to it.  So I don't think you'll ever get that "to work".  It's not just that it doesn't expect the list to mutate, it's also that significant processing is done on list entries, and the implementation has no way to know that you've added more entries.

Untested, I'd suggest trying this instead:  skip all that, and just keep a running count of threads still active.  A straightforward way is to use a `Condition` guarding a count.

Initialization:

```
self._count_cond = threading.Condition()
self._thread_count = 0
```

When `my_func` is entered (i.e., when a new thread starts):

```
with self._count_cond:
    self._thread_count += 1
```

When `my_func` is done (i.e., when a thread ends), for whatever reason (exceptional or not):

```
with self._count_cond:
    self._thread_count -= 1
    self._count_cond.notify() # wake up the waiting logic
```

And finally the main waiting logic:

```
with self._count_cond:
    while self._thread_count:
        self._count_cond.wait()
```

### POSSIBLE RACE

It seems possible that the thread count could reach 0 while work for a new thread has been submitted, but before its `my_func` invocation starts running (and so before `_thread_count` is incremented to account for the new thread).

So the:

```
with self._count_cond:
    self._thread_count += 1
```

part should really be done instead right *before* each occurrence of

```
self._thread_pool.submit(self.myfunc, id)
```

Or write a new method to encapsulate that pattern; e.g., like so:

```
def start_new_thread(self, id):
    with self._count_cond:
        self._thread_count += 1
    self._thread_pool.submit(self.myfunc, id)
```

### A DIFFERENT APPROACH

Offhand, I expect this could work too (but, again, haven't tested it):  keep all your code the same except change how you're waiting:

```
while self._futures:
    self._futures.pop().result()
```

So this simply waits for one thread at a time, until none remain.

Note that `.pop()` and `.append()` on lists are atomic in CPython, so no need for your own lock.  And because your `my_func()` code appends before the thread it's running in ends, the list won't become empty before all threads really are done.

### AND YET ANOTHER APPROACH

Keep the original waiting code, but rework the rest *not* to create new threads in case of exception.  Like rewrite `my_func` to return `True` if it quits due to an exception, return `False` otherwise, and start threads running a wrapper instead:

```
def my_func_wrapper(self, id):
    keep_going = True
    while keep_going:
        keep_going = self.my_func(id)
```

This may be especially attractive if you someday decide to use multiple processes instead of multiple threads (creating new processes can be a lot more expensive on some platforms).

### AND A WAY USING cf.wait()

Another way is to change just the waiting code:

```
while self._futures:
    fs = self._futures[:]
    for f in fs:
        self._futures.remove(f)
    concurrent.futures.wait(fs)
```

Clear?  This makes a copy of the list to pass to `.wait()`, and the copy is never mutated.  New threads show up in the original list, and the whole process is repeated until no new threads show up.

Which of these ways makes most sense seems to me to depend mostly on pragmatics, but there's not enough info about *all* you're doing for me to make a guess about that.

Comment: Thank you! But will there be a scenario where thread_count becomes 0 and the wait ends when previous workers have all finished their work and new workers haven't started?

Comment: I believe that's right!  See the new "Possible Race" section at the end.

Comment: Actually I'm using something similar to the last approach. My one is a while loop with a try-except inside, continuously running `wait(fs)` until there's no exception. Thanks for giving so many approaches!